# Content Filter Is Jumping When Button Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There was a similar question asked on here (not enough information was given) so no real solution was presented. I am using MixItUp to filter content within a framework (Foundation) based on a button being clicked. I noticed a weird movement that happens when a button is clicked. I have uploaded the files to be viewed here
http://cantaloupecreative.info/filter-code-snippet/

Comment: Can you describe the movement better? A screen capture might help. What browser & version does it happen on? I cannot repro it on Chrome.

Comment: Also not seeing any "jumping" in Chrome or Firefox for OSX, but I think I see what you're talking about in IE11 for Win 8.1. My guess is the plugin is using jQuery's `.animate()`, which is known to be choppy at times.

Comment: I am using Chrome v 38.0.2125.101 m. When I click the button the entire row hops to the right about 5-10px. The comment below has me looking into that class but all it did was add a scroll bar to my blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the animation fires, I see page elements jump to the right a bit. If that's what you're referring to, take a look at the scroll bar. When there aren't enough elements on the page, the scroll bar disappears and everything re-centers, which is likely what you're seeing. You can avoid this by permanently enabling or disabling the scroll bar with CSS

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

or something similar.

Comment: Do you add that onto a css class or is that needed on its own to wrap the entire document.

Comment: Sorry for the delay there. In this case, the entire document, because it's the scroll bar for the entire window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what I uncovered in my search for a solution. WebKit is overriding the css change I am making to my body class. You cannot use overflow-y in chrome because of this. Now when I was making the change to my sass file it wasn't compiling correctly. After hardcoding the webkit fix into my stylesheet I was able to remove the scrollbar on all toggled divs with the following code.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none
}
```

Obviously this only fixes half of the problem because now I am without a scrollbar. But it atleasts fixes the hoping issue.